# How is scaling done in multi classification SVM?

Tags: r, svm, multiclass-classification, e1071

I am working with R for solving a multi classification problem. I want to use `e1071`. How is scaling done for multiclass classification ? On this [page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-2/topics/svm%E2%80%9D), they say that

> “A logical vector indicating the variables to be scaled. If scale is of length 1, the value is recycled as many times as needed. Per default, data are scaled internally (both x and y variables) to zero mean and unit variance. The center and scale values are returned and used for later predictions.”

I am wondering how y is scaled. When we have m classes we have m columns for y, which they have different means and variances. So after scaling y, we have different number in each column for the same class! And it doesn’t make sense to me.

Could you please let me know what is going on in scaling? I am so curious to know that.

Also I am wondering what this mean:

"If scale is of length 1, the value is recycled as many times as needed."

Answer (score 0):

Let's have look at some information for the argument `scale`:

> A logical vector indicating the variables to be scaled. If scale is of length 1, the value is recycled as many times as needed. Per default, data are scaled internally (both x and y variables) to zero mean and unit variance.

The value expected here is a logical vector (so a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`). If this vector has as many values as you have columns in your matrix, then the columns are scaled or not according to your vector (eg. if you have `svm(..., scale = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), ...)` the first and third columns are scaled while the second one is not).

What happens during scaling is explained in the third sentence quoted above: "data are scaled [...] to zero mean and unit variance". To do this:

1. you substract each value of a column by the mean of this column (this is called centering), and
2. then you divide each value of this column by the columns standard deviation (this is the actual scaling).

You can reproduce the scaling with following example:

```
# create a data.frame with four variables
# as you can see the difference between each term of aa and bb is one
# and the difference between each term of cc is 21.63 while dd is random
(df <- data.frame(aa = 11:15,
                  bb = 1:5,
                  cc = 1:5*21.63,
                  dd = rnorm(5,12,4.2)))

# then we substract the mean of each column to this colum and
# put everything back together to a data.frame
(df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) {x-mean(x)})))
# you can observe that now the mean value of each column is 0 and
# that aa==bb because the difference between each term was the same

# now we divide each column by its standard deviation
(df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x) {x/sd(x)})))
# as you can see, the first three columns are now equal because the
# only difference between them was that cc == 21.63*bb

# the data frame df1 is now identical to what you would obtain by
# using the default scaling function `scale`
(df2 <- scale(df))
```

Scaling is necessary when your columns represent data on different scales. For example, if you wanted to distinguish individuals that are obese from lean ones you could collect their weight, height and waist-to-hip ratio. Weight would probably have values ranging from 50 to 95 kg, while height would be around 175 cm (± 20 cm) and waist-to-hip could range from 0.60 to 0.95. All these measurements are on different scales so that it is difficult to compare them. Scaling the variables solves this problem. Moreover, if one variable reaches high numerical values while the other ones do not, this variable will likely be given more importance during multivariate algorithms. Therefore scaling is advisable in most cases for such methods.

Scaling does affect the mean and the variance of each variable but as it is applied equally to each row (potentially belonging to different classes) this is not a problem.

Comment: I know the logic behind scaling, my question is how y (respond vectors {1,-1}) is scaled when we have multi classes.

Comment: I will edit my question, my problem is not scale function is scale in package e1071 for multi classification .

Comment: I don't know which classes you mean... If one of your columns is a factor, then you cannot scale it. If this factor defines the classes each row belongs to, just ignore this column. The scaling of the variables does not affect the differences between rows/classes, this is one of the properties of scaling

Comment: `scale` in the `svm` function from this package is identical to the standard `scale` function.